# How to set expiration date for ASP.NET_SessionId cookie?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, session-cookies

Here's how I have authentication configured in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Sigin" 
             name="MYCAUTH" 
             timeout="3000"  />
</authentication>
```

How can I make both `MYCAUTH` and `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookies use expiration?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439483/set-update-expiration-on-aspxauth-and-asp-net-sessionid-cookies ?

Comment: @The_Outsider that doesn't answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime expireDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, expireDate, true, string.Empty);
string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie authenticationCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
authenticationCookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationCookie);
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
```

Comment: thanks. is it possible to do with `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`? Also please note I updated my question. I need expiration for both `ASP.NET_SessionId` and `MYCAUTH`

Comment: `ASP.NET_SessionId` will be expired as soon as you close the browser. Aand those ar 2 different things anyway. See this post for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939533/cookie-confusion-with-formsauthentication-setauthcookie-method

Answer (score 1):

```
    var myCookie = Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
    if (myCookie != null)
    {
        HttpCookie respCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie", "MyValue");
        respCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        Response.Cookies.Set(myCookie);
    }
```